# All pythagorean triples appear on the rational unit circle.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b$ be positive integers and let $(x,y)$ satisfy 
$$x^2+y^2=1$$
$$ax-by=0$$

Prove that $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}^2$ iff  $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^2+b^2=n^2$.

Comment: What is your question? It seems that you have posted a proposition and immediately proved it yourself. Is your question about the proof? If so you should include the proof in the body of your question and highlight specifically your area(s) of confusion.

Comment: I just wanted to write out the steps of this proof out for myself. That's seems to be an intended feature of the website. When you post a question it offers "Post your question and answer Q&A style." Is this bad form?

Comment: I believe the "answering your own question" feature is if you have posed a question and later develop an answer on your own, so you can post it to your own question to "close off the question" and provide an answer for other viewers of the question. In this case I am just confused as to what your question is, as it seems that you have posed a question and answer to it simultaneously. Again, is your question about the proof?

Comment: I don't have a question. I am documenting some thinking that I have done. I mean... I kind of do have a question: Are their any hiccups when I replace the exponent $2$ with an $m$. In the post above. 

There is a feature that lets you immediately answer your own question. I am using this site perhaps a little too much like a blog for my mathematical thinking. I want to make sure that I keep the thoughts organized somewhere.

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23339/using-stackexchange-to-post-your-own-insights-q-a-style?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It seems this practice isn't loved here.

Comment: You (and others interested in Pythagorean Triples) may find this quite interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples

Comment: I have since found that wordpress is a an option to do this mathematical thinking without bugging stack exchange users. I will (eventually) migrate this post to my newly created blog. After the migration a question remains: Do I delete this post? 
So far this post has gotten 2 upvotes and 2 down votes.
I have no real horse in this race. If, after this is migrated, this post has a negative rating I will delete it. Otherwise I don't see the benefit... Clearly some users thought the question was worthy of an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b$ be positive integers and let $(x,y)$ satisfy 
$$x^m+y^m=1$$
$$ax-by=0$$

Prove that $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}^2$ iff  $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^m+b^m=n^m$.

**Proof**

Multiplying $x^m+y^m=1$ by $a^m$:

$$a^mx^m+a^my^m=a^m$$
Substituting $ax=by$
$$b^my^m+a^my^m=a^m$$

$$(a^m+b^m)y^m=a^m$$

$$y^m=\frac{a^m}{a^m+b^m}$$

$$y=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^m+b^m}}=\frac{a}{n}$$
Likewise,

$$x=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^m+b^m}}=\frac{b}{n}$$

If there does not exist any $n$ such that $n=\sqrt{a^m+b^m}$ then we can see that $x$ and $y$ cannot be rational as the numerator is an integer and the  denominator is the $m$th root of a non perfect power of $m$.

It looks to me like there is no problem generalizing in this way but this won't work in general for $$x^a+b^y=1$$

Comment: And indeed for $a \neq b$ we find that the solutions are not rational.  
$$x^2+y^4=1$$
$$2x-3y=0$$


$$2^2x^2+2^2y^4=2^2$$
$${3^2y}^2+2^2y^4=2^2$$
$${3^2y}^2+2^2y^4=2^2$$
$$3^2z+2^2z^2=2^2$$
$$4z^2+9z-4=0$$
Applying quadratic formula: 

$$z=\frac{\sqrt{145}-9}{8}$$
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{145}-9}{8}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Proof**

Multiplying $x^2+y^2=1$ by $a^2$:

$$a^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2$$
Substituting $ax=by$
$$b^2y^2+a^2y^2=a^2$$

$$(a^2+b^2)y^2=a^2$$

$$y^2=\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}$$

$$y=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{a}{n}$$
Likewise,

$$x=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{b}{n}$$

If there does not exist any $n$ such that $n=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ then we can see that $x$ and $y$ cannot be rational as the numerator is an integer and the  denominator is the square root of a non perfect square.

Comment: I really want to ask how this generalizes to the unit squircle. $x^m+y^m=1$ but I wanted to make sure I understood all the details of this case.

Comment: Another worthwhile generalization would be to multiple dimensions. 
What can be said of the sphere, etc?